# __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments

Tags: python, class, object, instance, traceback

I'm attempting to write a code for class and am having immense trouble with classes. The problem is for us to write a script with one class, `Car`, have the `speed` method set to '0', and display the speed over a series of ten iterations (calling `acceleration` and `brake` five times each). 
The error I'm getting is:

> > > `Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:/Users/Brown Bear/Documents/Wake Tech/CIS115/Python Documents/Lab14P1.py", line 36, in <module>
> > >           main()
> > >         File "C:/Users/Brown Bear/Documents/Wake Tech/CIS115/Python Documents/Lab14P1.py", line 27, in main
> > >           my_speed = Car()
> > >       TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'make', 'model', and 'speed'`

And this is the example of what the output should be:

```
Enter model of your car: Prius
Enter make of your car: Toyota
Current speed: 5
Current speed: 10
Current speed: 15
Current speed: 20
Current speed: 25
Current speed: 20
Current speed: 15
Current speed: 10
Current speed: 5
Current speed: 0
```

And this is my code:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, speed):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.speed = speed

    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed += 5

    def brake(self):
        self.speed -= 5

    def get_make(self):
        return self.make

    def get_model(self):
        return self.model

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed


def main():
    manuf = input('Enter the car make: ')
    mod = input('Enter the car model: ')

    my_speed = Car()

    for num in range(5):
        my_speed.accelerate()
        print('Current speed: ', my_speed.get_speed())
    for num in range(5):
        my_speed.brake()
        print('Current speed: ', my_speed.get_speed())

main()
```

I've spent a ridiculous amount of time on this particular problem and tried various ways, I've also researched similar questions previously asked on here but all are a bit too complex and I just need a simple solution. Any and all help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to enter the arguments when you initialize the class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create an instance of your class you are not passing any arguments:

```
 my_speed = Car()
```

But your definition says there are 3 required arguments:

```
def __init__(self, make, model, speed):
```

So you need to create an instance of Car and pass 3 arguments: make, model and speed.

```
my_speed = Car(manuf, mod, some_Speed_val)
```

Comment: I'm kicking myself for the simplicity of that fix.. You're an angel in my book. Thank a million, Andrew!